# Weird behavior with Range DataAnnotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have a Password field with `[Range(5, 10)]`.

If I input a correct value between 5 and 10, it displays a message error anyway. What might be causing this?

Comment: So you are saying that the Password is a __number__ from 5 to 9? pretty easy to crack I would say :) What you may need is the StringLength annotation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx

Comment: Errr..... Ouch? Lol. Brain Bug.

Comment: @Tallmaris - But i'd like a min lenght value too..

Comment: `StringLengthAttribute` also has [MinimumLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.minimumlength.aspx) property. `StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 5)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Range attribute is used  to determine what the minimum and maximum numeric value for the field should be. If you are trying to set min/max length I would suggest using `[StringLength(10, MinimumLength=5)]` attribute to set this constraint on the property which would do what I think it is your looking to for